# flutter AssetsAudioPlayer stop other instances

Tags: flutter, audio, assets, flutter-getx

I'm working on a quiz app and if the user selects a correct answer the app should play a success sound and if the answer is wrong the sound should be another one (e.g please try again )

my problem is when the user taps on another answer the old player are already working  I need to check if there is another instance of the player are playing and stop it

I'm using **assets_audio_player: ^3.0.4+1**

```
if (_correctAns != _selectedAns) {
  AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
    Audio("assets/audios/tryAgin.mp3"),
    showNotification: true,
  );
 
}
if (_correctAns == _selectedAns) {
  _assetsAudioPlayer.open(
    Audio("assets/audios/success.mp3"),
    showNotification: true,
  );
  Future.delayed(
    Duration(seconds: 2),
    () {
      nextQuestion();
    },
  );
  _numOfCorrectAns++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use isPlaying to check if there is an audio playing .... and as another solution u can stop the current playing sound in onPressed then play the new sound ... if u have any question I can help u

Comment: I did use _assetsAudioPlayer.stop(); but the sound didn't stop

Comment: @MohammedNoor, because you have created every time a new player instance.